# Meaning of verb phrase-ことだって、ある

Tags: grammar, particle-って

> 傷つけられ追い詰められたノラ犬は、人に襲いかかることだって、ある。
>   There are even times when a wounded and cornered stray dog will attack a human.

In my TL I have guessed that ことだって、ある is ことがある (there are times when...) with the が being replaced by だって to give the meaning "there are **even** times when...". Is this correct? Why is there a comma here?

My other thought was that って might be quoting the stuff before it, but I got stuck with that line of reasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got this one correct.

> 「Verb Phrase or Mini-Sentence + こと**だって**、ある」

means:

> "There are ***also/even*** times when ~~~."

It is sayig that ~~~ is totally possible.  「～～だって」 basically means 「～～もやはり」.

The comma there is unnecessary and it is usually not used at all.  The author might have had a reason for using a comma, but without further context, we could not be certain of it.  Most likely, it was for emphasizing the fact that the stray dogs actually could attack humans at times.

NOTE: This 「だって」 should not be confused with the sentence-ending 「～～～だって」, which is ***quotative***.  "~~~~, he said.", "~~~, it says", etc.